# Reformat a Pandas dataframe with a tuple in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains a tuple column as follows.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [('A', 0), ('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 0), ('B', 1), ('B', 2)], 'col2': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# Split the tuple to two cols and drop the tuple col                                                                                                                                                    
df[['b1', 'b2']] = pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].tolist(), index=df.index)                                                                                                                       
print(df)
  col2 b1  b2
0     1  A   0
1     1  A   1
2     1  A   2
3     2  B   0
4     2  B   1
5     2  B   2
```

What I am trying to do is to reformat this dataframe in the most efficient way and generate a new one where 0,1,2 are the columns and A, B are the row names. so I can write to a csv file.

```
   0  1  2
A  1  1  1
B  2  2  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can do `pivot` with `rename_axis`

```
out = df.pivot(index='b1',columns='b2',values='col2').\
          rename_axis(None,axis=1).rename_axis(None)
Out[101]: 
   0  1  2
A  1  1  1
B  2  2  2
```